# Notepad Regex Formatting

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, notepad

Lets say i have 100000 words in a list
( Example )
Apple
Orange
Grape
Bannana
.... etc

and i need them in this format

```
<command name="FindRep" enabled="True">
    <find xml:space="preserve">FRUITS</find>
    <replace></replace>
    <flags></flags>
  </command>
```

but changed FRUITS
to Apples, Orange. Grape, etc etc

```
  <command name="FindRep" enabled="True">
    <find xml:space="preserve">Apple</find>
    <replace></replace>
    <flags></flags>
  </command>
  <command name="FindRep" enabled="True">
    <find xml:space="preserve">Orange</find>
    <replace></replace>
    <flags></flags>
  </command>
  <command name="FindRep" enabled="True">
    <find xml:space="preserve">Grape</find>
    <replace></replace>
    <flags></flags>
  </command>
```

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+`
- Replace with: `<command name="FindRep" enabled="True">\n    <find xml:space="preserve">$0</find>\n    <replace></replace>\n    <flags></flags>\n</command>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
```

`\S+`

**Replacement:**

```
<command name="FindRep" enabled="True">     # literally
\n                                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
    <find xml:space="preserve">             # literally
$0                                      # the whole match (i.e. the fruit name)
</find>                                     # literally
\n                                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
    <replace></replace>                     # literally
\n                                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
    <flags></flags>                         # literally
\n                                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
</command>                                  # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regular expression, just replace the space character between the fruits with:

```
</find><replace></replace><flags></flags></command><command name="FindRep" enabled="True"><find xml:space="preserve">
```

Then manually fix the beginning and end of the file.

Comment: No end-lines in your solution.

Comment: @harrymc So what? That's what the XML addin for np++ does. If you really must, include `\n` in the replace string

Comment: So what? You should add it in, if it's part of your answer.

Comment: @harrymc Feel free to add your own improved answer

Comment: Accepting comments for improving our answers is part of being on this site.